# Problem with indentation of subitem in list

Tags: lists, indentation, paragraphs

I'm very new to LaTeX and i'm currently writing my theses in it. I want to create a list with items and subitems. But i have problem with the indentation. I'm sure it's a beginner mistake, but i can't figure it out.

[image: Problem]

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{What is Lorem Ipsum?} \\
    \subitem Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. \\
    \item \textbf{Why do we use it?} \\
    \subitem Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. \\
\end{itemize}
```

What am i doing wrong here ? I just want the text to start where the other sentences of that paragraph start, not with that empty space.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{What is Lorem Ipsum?} 

     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
    \item \textbf{Why do we use it?}

     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works, Thanks !